# ArrayList in comboBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, arraylist, combobox

I need help with creating an `ArrayList` that adds words into a `ComboBox`, which then allows the user to click on the word and then it gets inserted into a `RichTextBox`. I do have the following code but it does not work. Hope someone could assist me please.

```
public partial class WordEditorApp : Form
{
//Creating an arraylist for the combobox.
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

public WordEditorApp()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Initializing the radio buttons.
    upperCase.Checked = false;
    lowerCase.Checked = false;

    //Adding items to the arraylist.
    al.Add("Grams");
    al.Add("Aristrocrats");
    al.Add("Sophisticated");
    al.Add("Corruption");
    al.Add("Interrupt");
    al.Add("Operation");
    al.Add("Decision");
    al.Add("Bantam");
    al.Add("Brochure");
    al.Add("Hydraulics");
    al.Add("Properties");

    //for loop to add items to the arraylist.
    for (int i = 0; i < al.Count; i++)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(al[i].ToString());
    }
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Selected word from the combo box is appended into the textbox.
        richTextBox1.AppendText(ArrayList.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

Comment: 'Doesn't work' is __not a helpful__ problem description! - Also: `ArrayList` is practically depracated and replaced by `List<T>`, in your case a `List<string>` Of course __neither have__ a selection, hence your errors

Answer (score 2):

A simpler alternative

```
string[] al = { "Grams", "Aristrocrats", "Sophisticated", "Corruption", "Interrupt", 
               "Operation", "Decision", "Bantam", "Brochure", "Hydraulics", "Properties" };
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(al);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

Start by using current, efficient, type-safe and extensible objects and methods:

```
    List<string> words = new List<string>()
    {
        "Grams", "Aristrocrats", "Sophisticated",
        "Corruption", "Interrupt", "Operation",
        "Decision", "Bantam", "Brochure", "Hydraulics", "Properties"
    };

    comboBox1.Items.AddRange(words.ToArray());
```

Then I would not append the text but set it as the SelectedText; this means the user can insert it anwhere, thus providing append, insert and replace all in one go:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectedText = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

Adding a space after each word may also be a friendly idea..

Note that if you only want to load a fixed number of items you can do it like this as well:

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new[] { "Grams", "Aristrocrats", "Sophisticated",
             "Corruption", "Interrupt", "Operation", "Decision", 
             "Bantam", "Brochure", "Hydraulics", "Properties" });
```

Here no local list or array is needed and the type is resolved from the values.

But if you declare a `List<string>` at class level you can expand it with new words the user enters and later store it in a file, creating a growing word list..

Answer (score 1):

I thing this is wrong:

```
   //Selected word from the combo box is appended into the textbox.
    richTextBox1.AppendText(ArrayList.SelectedItem.ToString());
                              ^
```

ArrayList doesnt have a static property called `SelectedItem`.
Did you mean `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(comboBox1.Text);
```

You are trying to append text from ArrayList..

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on `ArrayList` class (which is *deprecated*):

```
// static: you want just one instance for all WordEditorApp instances
private static ArrayList al = new ArrayList() { 
  "Grams",
  "Aristrocrats",
  "Sophisticated",
  "Corruption",
  "Interrupt",
  "Operation",
  "Decision",
  "Bantam",
  "Brochure",
  "Hydraulics",
  "Properties"
};

...

comboBox1.Items.AddRange(al.OfType<String>());
```

a better design is to change `ArrayList` to `List<String>` or `String[]`:

```
private static String[] al = new String[] {
  "Grams",
  "Aristrocrats",
  ... 
  "Properties"
};

...

// No need in OfType<String>() here
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(al);
```